# ¿Como eliminar un caracter repetido en C?

Tags: c++, c

Estoy llenando un formulario con validaciones y hay un campo que me pide promedio, y una de las reglas para validarlo es que solo contenga un punto decimal.

Ejemplo:

Si el usuario teclea 2..2, que vuelva a preguntar el promedio.

¿Alguien tiene una idea de como hacerlo?
Gracias. :D

Tengo este código, pero me elimina todos los repetidos, yo solo quiero que elimine el punto '.'

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>  
int main() 
{ 
    char resultado[27]=""; 
    char palabra[50];
    int i=0,j=0; 
    printf("Ingresa una frase!\n");scanf("%s",palabra); 
    while(palabra[i]) 
    { 
        if(!strchr(resultado,palabra[i])) 
            resultado[j++]=palabra[i]; 
        i++; 
    } 
    resultado[j]='\0'; 
    printf("\nEl resultado seria!\n%s",resultado); 

    getchar(); 
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Hola Jonathan, muestranos el codigo que tienes asi sabemos como modificarlo

Comment: http://todocporelinv.blogspot.mx/2011/04/contar-ocurrencias-de-letras-en-una.html

Comment: Cuente el número de ocurrencias de cada vocal
http://listas.conclase.net/pipermail/cconclase_listas.conclase.net/2009-July/006378.html

Comment: Listo, gracias por el consejo. :)

Comment: No queda claro si quieres validar la entrada o corregirla... por un lado dices "*Si el usuario teclea 2..2, que vuelva a preguntar el promedio*" y por el otro creas un código pensado para eliminar los puntos repetidos O_o

Answer (score 3):

La solución de [Alvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/7639/2742) funcona; sin embargo es una solución muy [c](/questions/tagged/c); dado que también has etiquetado la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) te propongo usar la librería [`<regex>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)(como ya ha sugerido Alvaro), que permite hacer las operaciones en pocas líneas:

```
bool punto_repetido(const std::string &entrada)
{
    std::regex puntos{R"(\d*\.{2,}\d*)"};
    return std::regex_match(entrada, puntos);
}
```

La función `punto_repetido` indicará si el usuario ha tecleado un número con dos puntos en lugar de uno; puedes corregir la entrada con esta otra función:

```
std::string corrige(const std::string &entrada)
{
    std::regex puntos{R"(\.{2,})"};
    return std::regex_replace(entrada, puntos, ".");
}
```

Puedes ver el código en funcionamiento [aquí](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5ei5O8KzNpAONGsR).

Ten en cuenta que sólo valora entradas que se parezcan a un número (no valorará `2.2.2`, ni `aaadfa...a` por ejemplo).

Comment: Me has pillado, hice las pruebas como proyecto C y no en C++ :P

Comment: No tiene nada de malo que el código sea [tag:c]; sin embargo el autor de la pregunta deberá escoger un lenguaje u otro pues por mucho que en algunos círculos se insista en que *son lo mismo*, sin duda son lenguajes muy diferentes aunque sus paradigmas sean casi iguales.

Comment: Decir que C y C++ son lo mismo es una barbaridad. Supongo que lo dirán porque el código C generalmente funciona en compiladores C++, pero eso sería como comparar un Seat Panda con un Ferrari y decir que son lo mismo porque los dos son coches y la palanca de cambios sigue la misma estructura.

Answer (score 0):

El código que compartes elimina todos los caracteres repetidos en la cadena, pero sólo quieres eliminar algunos caracteres (los puntos) que haya después del primer punto.

Para ello podrías seguir el siguiente algoritmo:

1. Atraviesa la cadena leída
2. Si el carácter no es un punto

   1. Copia el carácter al resultado
3. Si el carácter es un punto

   1. Si es el primer punto que se encuentra

      1. Copia el punto al resultado

El código sería así:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{ 
    char resultado[27]=""; 
    char palabra[50];
    int i=0,j=0; 
    int punto = 0; // variable centinela para comprobar el número de puntos

    printf("Ingresa una frase!\n");
    scanf("%s",palabra);

    // atraviesa la palabra leida
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(palabra); i++) {
        // si la palabra es un punto
        if (palabra[i] == '.') {
            // y es el primer punto que se encuentra
            if (punto == 0) {
                // activa el centinela y añade el punto al resultado
                punto = 1;
                resultado[j++] = '.';
            }
        // si no es un punto, añade el carácter/número al resultado
        } else {
            resultado[j++] = palabra[i];
        }
    }

    resultado[j] = '\0';

    printf("\nEl resultado seria!\n%s",resultado); 

    getchar(); 
    return(0);
}
```

---

Una alternativa un poco diferente y que se parece más al código que mostraste:

1. Inicializa las variables `i` y `j` a 0.
2. Inicializa la variable `resultado` a "".
3. Usa `strchr` para encontrar el primer punto en la cadena leída
4. Si se encontró un punto

   1. Actualiza el valor de `i` a la posición del punto en la cadena
   2. Actualiza el valor de `resultado` a la subcadena hasta el punto (puedes usar `memcpy` para ello)
   3. Actualiza el valor de `j` a la longitud de `resultado`
5. Atraviesa la cadena leída desde la posición `i`.

   1. Si el carácter no es un punto, añádelo al resultado

Si te fijas los pasos 1, 2 y 5 son (casi) iguales a lo que ya tienes, y sólo tendrías que añadir los pasos 3 y 4, que son para actualizar las variables utilizadas en el paso 5 y siguientes.

El código sería así:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>  
int main() 
{ 
    char resultado[50] = ""; 
    char palabra[50];
    int i=0,j=0; 
    char *subcadena;

    printf("Ingresa una frase!\n");scanf("%s",palabra);

    // si se encuentra un punto en la palabra
    if (subcadena = strchr(palabra, '.')) {
        // actualiza los valores necesitados
        i = subcadena - palabra + 1;
        memcpy( resultado, palabra, i);
        j = strlen(resultado);
    }

    // atraviesa la palabra
    while(palabra[i]) 
    {
        // solo insertando los caracteres que no son puntos 
        if(palabra[i] != '.') 
            resultado[j++]=palabra[i]; 
        i++; 
    } 
    resultado[j]='\0'; 

    printf("\nEl resultado seria!\n%s",resultado); 

    getchar(); 
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Aunque personalmente, si estuviera en tu posición, me plantearía si en lugar de procesar la cadena leída lo que haría sería usar expresiones regulares para detectar si es válida o no, y volver a preguntar hasta que el usuario introdujese un dato válido